# Excel formula to find last non-blank and numerical cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently using this formula to find the last non-blank cell in a row:

```
=IF(AD215="CLOSED",MATCH(9.999999E+306,'686'!$P215:$AA215),0)
```

Is there any way to edit this so that the formula will tell me the last non-blank and numerical cell in a row?

Comment: Can you add a new row in your sheet in which you put in a formula that checks if the cell in the row in question is numeric?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you quote is **already** finding the `position` (within '686'!$P215:$AA215) of the last `numeric` cell in the range so I'm not really clear how you want to amend it.

If you want the actual numeric value rather than the position just replace `MATCH` with `LOOKUP` in your formula.

If that doesn't answer your question then please give a concrete example - what do you have in that range and what do you want to find (specifically) given that example?